# Как вывести записи по произвольному полю используя select и option в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Фильтер, переключатель для сортировки:

```
<div class="filter">
    <select class="color">
      <option value="0">Выберите цвет</option>
      <option value="1">Чёрный</option>
      <option value="2">Белый</option>
      <option value="3">Красный</option>
    </select>
    <select class="size">
      <option value="0">Выберите размер</option>
      <option value="1">S</option>
      <option value="2">M</option>
      <option value="3">XL</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Вывод записей:

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'category_name' => 'shirts',
      'numberposts' => 0,
      'order' => 'DSC',
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'suppress_filters' => true,
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post);
      ?>
      <div class="shirt">
<span class="color"><?php if ($value = get_field('color')):?><?php echo $value;?><?php endif;?></span>
<span class="size"><?php if ($value = get_field('size')):?><?php echo $value;?><?php endif;?></span>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе option в select выводились только нужные посты. Например, выбираем Цвет: черный, Размер: M, выводится пост именно с этими произвольным полями. Желательно без плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что при попытке фильтрации у вас получается такой url:
`http://site.ru/catalog/?color=black&size=1`

Если параметры у записей указаны произвольными полями, то делаем так:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'category_name' => 'shirts',
  'numberposts' => 0,
  'order' => 'DSC',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'meta_query' => Array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
       'key'     => 'color',
       'value'   => $_REQUEST['color'],
       'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
       'key'     => 'size',
       'value'   => $_REQUEST['size'],
       'compare' => '='
    )
  ),
);
```

Рекомендую изучить WP_Query() и параметры из него)